# Скрипт для автозамены символов в spreadsheets

Tags: google-api, google-docs-api, google-apps-script

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Google формы при сохранении данных в таблицу изменяют в числах разделитель десятичной части с «запятой» на «точку». В итоге вместо цифр в таблице имеем текст. Сейчас меняю в столбцах «точку» на «запятую» вручную через "Меню-Правка-Найти и заменить". Но хотелось бы это автоматизировать. По разным примерам из Интернета написал следующее:

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name : "Замена точки на запятую",functionName : "ReplaceDotToComma"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Скрипты", entries);
};

function ReplaceDotToComma() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Страница 2")
  var r = sheet.getRange("A:B");
  var rws = r.getNumRows();
  var cls = r.getNumColumns();
  var i, j, a, fnd, rpl;
  fnd = ".";
  rpl = ",";
  for (i=1;i<=rws;i++) {
    for (j=1;j<=cls;j++) {
      a=r.getCell(i, j);
      a=a.toString().replace(fnd, rpl);
      r.getCell(i, j).setValue(a);
    }
  }
 }
```

Но что-то не работает. Прошу помощи, как правильно написать команду замены? Готов на любую помощь. Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

Действительно ли вам нужен скрипт? Попробуйте настроить Форму.

Действительно, формат числа поддерживается "нормально" только для систем, где разделителем является точка. Но вы можете создать текстовое поле с проверкой на значение, используя регулярное выражение с паттерном:

```
 \d+(?:,{1}\d+)
```

- [Пример формы](http://goo.gl/forms/bAECXLtECT)
- [Проверка ответов - Справка Google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3378864?hl=ru)

Comment: `{1}` обязательно?

Comment: Ну, так всегда можно попробовать. Пример формы есть.

Answer (score 1):

Я переделал код и получилось то, что нужно.  Возможно, что кто-нибудь сможет его еще улучшить, чтобы это было более красиво

```
function replaceOKVED(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("transliteraciya")
  var sheetOKVED = ss.getSheetByName("ALFAVIT")
  var arrOKVED = sheetOKVED.getRange("A2:B"+sheetOKVED.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues()
  var arrKeys = sheet.getRange("A2:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getDisplayValues()

  for(var i = 0; i < arrKeys.length; i++){
    if(arrKeys[i][0].search("заменить 1") != -1){
      var okvedNumber = arrKeys[i][1]
      for(var j = 0; j<arrOKVED.length; j++){
        if(okvedNumber == arrOKVED[j][0]){
          sheet.getRange(i+2, 2).setValue(arrOKVED[j][1])
          break
        }
      }
    } else if(arrKeys[i][0].search("заменить") != -1){
      var arrOkvedNumbers = arrKeys[i][1].split("")
      var arrOkvedNames = []
      for(var l = 0; l < arrOkvedNumbers.length;l++){
        for(var k = 0;k<arrOKVED.length; k++){
          if(arrOkvedNumbers[l] == arrOKVED[k][0]){
            arrOkvedNames.push(arrOKVED[k][1])
          }
        }
      }
      var fullName = arrOkvedNames.join("")
      sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue(fullName)
    }
  }
  ss.toast("Все готово", "Внимание", 5)
}
```

для меню

```
function onOpen(e){
  //updateXmlList()
  addMenu_()
}

function addMenu_(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu("МОЕ МЕНЮ")
  .addItem("Заменить буквы", "replaceOKVED")
  .addToUi()
}
```

1) создайте таблицу с названием "ALFAVIT"
    - в первом столбце запишите то, что меняем
    - во втором - на что меняем

2) на любой странице в столбце "А" пишем слово "заменить" в столбце "В" текст которых хотим заменить

Я новичок, и у меня не хватает опыта - не судите строго. Если кто улучшит решение - буду рад.

Comment: Ответы не предназначены для публикации новых вопросов. Лучше опубликуйте свою проблему отдельным вопросом =/

Comment: @Suvitruf по-моему это все же ответ :)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов хм, смутило "Если кто улучшит решение - буду рад". Если ответ, тогда пускай будет (:

Comment: Я взял на себя смелость скорректировать текст Вашего ответа. Гляньте, если я правильно Вас интерпретировал, то есть смысл принять правку.

Answer (score 0):

В Google Docs Spreadsheets есть SUBSTITUTE

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее ваше решение. Подробный и качественный ответ поможет гораздо большему количеству людей, столкнувшихся с подобной проблемой.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю что `a=r.getCell(i, j).GetValue();` должно быть

Comment: Вы подозреваете или это ответ?

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/169024)

Comment: @br3t, вроде ж похоже на правду?

Comment: @Qwertiy , похоже, но "Подозреваю" похоже на то, что автор ответа не пытался проверить свой ответ, а предположения, имхо, лучше в комменты.

Comment: @br3t, ну не всегда. Вполне можно в ответы, а если автор вопроса напишет, что не помогло, то просто удалить. Я так иногда делаю.

Answer (score 0):

```
=(SUBSTITUTE(substitute(H5,",",""),".",","))
```

Где Н5 это строка

Попробуй это